# Question about proof of Lindelöf Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, continuity

> Supose that $\gamma : [0,1] \to \overline{\mathbb{D}}$ is continuous, $\gamma(t) \in \mathbb{D}$ for $0 \le t < 1$ and $\gamma(1) = 1$. Suppose that $f \in H(\mathbb{D})$ is bounded. If $f(\gamma(t)) \to L$ as $t \to 1$, then $\lim_{r \to 1^-} f(r) = L. \ [\ldots]$

---

Proof: We can asume $L = 0$ and $|f| < 1$. Let $K = \{z \in \overline{\mathbb{D}} : \Re(z) \ge 0\}$ and fix $\epsilon \in (0,1)$; now choose $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(\gamma(t))| < \epsilon$ for all $t \in [0, 1)$ with $|1 - \gamma(t)| < \delta$.

---

I don't understand how it's possible to choose that $\delta$, because from the fact that $f \circ \gamma \to 0$ as $t \to 1$ it results that $\forall \epsilon > 0 \ \exists \delta > 0$ s.t. $\forall \ 0 < |t-1| < \delta$ we have $|f(\gamma(t))| < \epsilon$. But how to continue?

**Edit:** What I've added:

In particular, for $\gamma$ to be defined, we need to have $t \in [0,1]$, so we obtain $\forall \epsilon > 0 \ \exists \delta > 0$ s.t. $\forall \ t \in [0,1)$ with $|t-1| < \delta$ we have $|f(\gamma(t))| < \epsilon$.
From the fact that $\gamma$ is continuous at $t = 1$ it implies that $\exists \delta_0 > 0$ s.t. $\forall t \in [0,1]$ with $|t - 1| < \delta_0$ we have that $|\gamma(t)-1| < \delta$. 
Now, if $\delta_0 \ge \delta$ we obtain that $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0$ s.t. $|f(\gamma(t))| < \epsilon$ for all $t \in [0,1)$ with $|1-\gamma(t)| < \delta$. 
On the other way, if $\delta_0 < \delta$, we have that, $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta_0 > 0$ s.t. $|f(\gamma(t))| < \epsilon$ for all $t \in [0,1)$ with $|1-\gamma(t)| < \delta_0$.

Comment: are you sure you quoted the theorem right and you do not need an additional hypothesis like $\gamma$ is nontangential?

Comment: @Conrad yes. I've checked again. It's Lemma 14.4 from Complex Made Simple of David C. Ullrich.

Comment: @Conrad I've tried something. Can you check if it works please? I've added an edit to the post.

Comment: yes you are right - the thing is that $C=\gamma[0,1]$ is compact so if you fix $\epsilon$ you can find $\delta_1$ st $|f(\gamma(t))| < \epsilon, t \ge 1-\delta_1$; but the image of $f([0, 1-\delta_1])$ is a compact disjoint from $1$ so it has a distance $\delta_2 >0$ from $1$ so pick $\delta <\delta_2$ hence $|1-\gamma(t)| < \delta$ forces $t>1-\delta_1$ where the inequality holds

Comment: not sure about your edit since it's kind of confusing (especially the last proposition since you fix $\delta_0$ but then you pick it again - maybe you wanted to express what I mentioned in the comment above but you have to be careful with notation

Comment: @Conrad I think I don't understand very good. And, shouldn't be $\gamma([0,1-\delta_1])$ is compact disjoint from $1$?

Comment: correct it should be $\gamma([0,1-\delta_1])$ compact disjoint from $1$ so if $\delta<\delta_2$ we have that $|1-\gamma(t)| <\delta_2$ forces $t>1-\delta_1$ so $|f(\gamma(t)| <\epsilon$

Comment: And by distance $\delta_2$ I think you are referring to infimum of distances between any point from $\gamma([0,1-\delta_1])$ and $1$. Is this true?

Comment: no - $\delta_2$ is the infimum (minimum by compacity) of the distance between the image of $\gamma$ on the interval $[0, 1-\delta_1]$ and $1$